# Qt capture QCamera too dark

Tags: qt, video-capture, capture

I was using opencv camera support to capture images in Qt, since Qt5.2 now has QCamera and QCameraImageCapture, I'm porting to it, with great code simplification.

But the image captured is way too dark, while the frame exposed by QCameraViewfinder has the correct luminance. Alas, QWidget::grab() doesn't work on QCameraViewfinder.

Also the camera demo code behaves the same way (changing 'Exposure Compensation' does not have any effect on captured image).

Any hint about this problem ? I'm working on Ubuntu 64 bit with an USB WebCam.

Comment: Its possible that the format of the image is off.  Have you double checked the specs of the camera you are using and making sure it is interpreting the pixels properly?  Qt can handle a lot of image formats, but its possible it auto-assigned the wrong format.

Comment: @phyatt: I tried to set the pixel format, but nothing changed. Of course, there are many variations, I didn't tried everything. What's strange it's the display done by QCameraViewfinder is good. Just capture() loose the luminance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Even the example apps has that issue. It shows fine but when it captures it shows the image like it has no whitebalance. it is like it resets the camera just before taking a picture.

Comment: Looks like a k/ubuntu issue, the same code in windows provides excellent results. and fasts too.

Comment: @Nande: just tried Qt 5.4 (on Ubuntu). Still buggy...

Comment: Mine is Kubuntu 14.04 64 bits (amd). i tried in two machines with the same os (different cpus), and with two different webcams (using uvc) and the result was the same, only one cam was faster to regain full brightness. I'm using QtOpenSource online installer. Qt 5.3 and 5.4 have the same issue

Comment: Using WebcamStudio to make a loopback takes the problem away but introduces 2 seconds delay. That's unacceptable for taking pictures :/

Comment: Six years later: works perfectly on Windows but I have this issue on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Qt way to pull images from a viewer is to use another one of the `QCameraXXX` classes based off `QMediaBindableInterface`...

This shows an example of pulling info off the camera.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qcameraimagecapture.html#details

```
camera = new QCamera;

viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder();
viewfinder->show();

camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);

imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);

camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
camera->start();
//on half pressed shutter button
camera->searchAndLock();

//on shutter button pressed
imageCapture->capture();

//on shutter button released
camera->unlock();
```

Then to handle the capture image, you can connect to the `imageCaptured` signal, and you have a `QImage` to work with.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qcameraimagecapture.html#imageCaptured

Hope that helps.

Comment: it still gets the image like it is unbalanced, i dont know why, it even happens on the camera example